# How can I force a css flex child to be the only on its row?

Tags: html, css

The parent is a flex container which displays the children in a row, with wrapping enabled. Most components are fine when positioned next to each other in a row, and that all works. But one of the components is an input slider which I prefer to place on its own row (100% container width).

I can set the slider to 100% width... but the margin and padding mess everything up and cause horizontal scrollbars. Of course I could set overflow to hidden... but then I'm missing out on content.

So how do I tell the flex container to put this child on its own row?

- parent: display flex, row wrap
- child: flex 1 0 auto

Javascript is a possibility, but I would prefer not to use it in this case.

Comment: Post some code or link to jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bt86k1rj/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the full-width child to `flex: 1 100%;`. Here, [have a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4p1vxyn/1).

[Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/1gut7jdt/1/) applied to a fork of your fiddle.

Comment: I have to say, I don't really understand what the `flex-shrink` property does; but I have worked out that setting it to `100%` makes the item full-size :)

Comment: That works indeed! How does this work, though? (Just saw your comment: O, okay haha!)

Comment: Sadly, even the normally-excellent [Mozilla Dev Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) is somewhat unhelpful.